# Getting errors when using useFieldArray in a React-Hook-Form implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a custom MUI Autocomplete component that is utilized on a form using React-Hook-Form useFieldArray function. It produces the following warning:

```
The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `{"id":"1","name":"Electrical High Voltage"}`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

I'm not sure on how to fix this. The component works well on other forms/components, but seems to throw the above warning when used within a useFieldArray function. The component is still functional and loads the correct data.

I'm using MongoDB and am storing my data as such... with my code structures as below...

```
...
"eiclDetail": {
...
...
      "checklistDetail": [
        {
          "code": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Electrical High Voltage"
          },
          ...
          ...
        }
      ],
    },
...
```

Custom Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

export const MUIAutocomplete = ({
  disableClearable,
  disableCloseOnSelect,
  color,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      name={props.name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue={props.multiple ? [] : null}
      render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          {...field}
          readOnly={props.readOnly}
          disableCloseOnSelect={disableCloseOnSelect ? true : false}
          multiple={props.multiple}
          disableClearable={disableClearable ? true : false}
          options={props.options}
          getOptionLabel={(
            option 
          ) =>
            option?.name === undefined ||
            option?.name === "" ||
            option?.name === [] ||
            option?.name
          }
          renderOption={(props, option) => {
            return (
              <Box
                component="li"
                {...props}
                key={option.id}
                color={
                  color
                    ? color.map((value) =>
                        value.id === option.id ? "green" : null
                      )
                    : null
                }
              >
                {option.name}
              </Box>
            );
          }}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
            value === undefined || value === "" || option.id === value.id
          }
          onChange={(_, data) => field.onChange(data)}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              {...props}
              error={error ? true : false}
              helperText={error ? error.message : ""}
            />
          )}
          renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
            tagValue.map((option, index) => (
              <div style={{ width: "100%", mt: 1 }} key={option.id}>
                <Chip
                  {...getTagProps({ index })}
                  label={option.name}
                  key={option.id}
                  variant="outlined"
                  deleteIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
                  color="primary"
                />
              </div>
            ))
          }
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

and my parent component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

import updateAction from "../../../actions/updateAction";
import clearAction from "../../../actions/clearAction";

import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardHeader from "@mui/material/CardHeader";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";

import { MUIAutocomplete } from "../../../shared/components/common/MUIAutocomplete";

const ChecklistItemDetail = () => {
  const [autocompleteOptions, setAutocompleteOptions] = useState([]);

  const { state } = useStateMachine({
    updateAction,
    clearAction,
  });

  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    name: "eiclDetail.checklistDetail",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setAutocompleteOptions([
      { id: 1, name: "Electrical High Voltage" },
      { id: 2, name: "Electrical Low Voltage" },
      { id: 3, name: "Radiation" },
      { id: 4, name: "Mechanical" },
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader />
        <CardContent>
          {fields.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <MUIAutocomplete
                name={`eiclDetail.checklistDetail.${index}.code`}
                label="Code"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                fullWidth
                options={autocompleteOptions}
              />
            );
          })}
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default ChecklistItemDetail;
```

I've cut the code down for clarity. Please advise on a potential fix to this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you are getting is because the value you are passing to the `Autocomplete` component does not match any of the options.

You are using strict equality check (`===`) to compare the value and the options. However, in your case, the `value.id` is a string because of how MongoDB stores the data. Therefore, the equality check will always fail.

So you need to change either `===` to `==` or `value.id` type to integer.

For example:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === "" ||
  option.id === parseInt(value.id, 10)
}
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-liskov-dhvx7f?file=/src/App.js).